# What is the meaning of: [Note] (if you use '-fpermissive' G++ will accept your code) in this concept?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing a function to divide each element by 2 in a 2D array. I also get the error message `'j' was not declared in this scope` on the line `return arr[i][j];`. Please advise:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


double halfs(double (*arr)[2], int r, int c); // include type dbl in front of (*arr)

int main(){

    double data[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    halfs (data, 2, 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        cout << data[1][i] << " "; // prints 1.5 2.0
    }

return 0;
}

double halfs(int (*arr)[2], int r, int c){
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++){
            arr[i][j] / 2;
        }
    }
    return arr[i][j];
}
```

I updated the code to (see below) and now get a `[Error] ld returned 1 exit status`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void halfs(double (*arr)[2], int r, int c); // include type dbl in front of (*arr)

int main(){

    double data[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    halfs (data, 2, 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        cout << data[1][i] << " "; // prints 1.5 2.0
    }

return 0;
}

void halfs(int (*arr)[2], int r, int c){
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++){
            arr[i][j] = arr[i][j] / 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `arr[i][j] / 2;`. This will do absolutely nothing, whatsoever. The result of the division gets thrown away, so the compiler will not generate any code for this. `return arr[i][j];` -- `i` and `j` do not exist any more.

Comment: `return arr[i][j];` the `j` used there is not in scope.

Comment: I removed the `return arr[i][j];` line and now I get `ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: `void halfs(int (*arr)[2], int r, int c){ ...` (and the key to formatting in comments is to use *back-ticks*, e.g. `'\`'` not single-quotes `:)` And you probably want `arr[i][j] /= 2;` to half each value (shorthand for .`arr[i][j] = arr[i][j] / 2;`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I tried void before but I got was `ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: When your return type is `void`, the function should not return any value (it can contain a `return;` alone to exit the function early, but no `return something;` allowed) -- but that isn't your problem. The `ld returned 1 exit status` means your program was not `linked` to an executable `ld` is the linker that takes the object file(s) and turns those into an executable. You likely forgot to include a needed header file. If you removed `using namespace std;`, you need `std::cout`. (or you didn't change both `halfs()` declarations -- thanks @JaMiT)

Comment: @JaMiT I have it at both declaration and at definition. I also tried `arr[i][j] = arr[i][j] / 2;`

Comment: @YokoKoko - edit your question and *Add* what you have now below your original code (do not *Delete* your original code -- or all comments and answers won't make sense anymore)

Comment: `void halfs(int (*arr)[2], int r, int c){` with `int (*arr)[2]` **should be** `double (*arr)[2]` -- they have to match `:)` -- simply declaring your function above `main()` will eliminate the chance of a mismatch between your prototype and the actual function *definition*.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It worked!!!!! I failed to match the type in the declaration and definition. Maybe I should go to sleep now. I'm starting to make sillier and sillier mistakes haha. Thanks a lot, David!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212395/discussion-between-yoko-koko-and-david-c-rankin).

Answer (score 2):

The error message is reasonably straight-forward. You are using `j` outside its scope. Are you aware of what the scope of a variable is? Here is an illustration:

```
double halfs(int (*arr)[2], int r, int c){
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++){    // <-- Begin scope of j (definition)
            arr[i][j] / 2;
        }                               // <-- End scope of j   (end of block)
    }
    return arr[i][j];                   // <-- not in the scope of j
}
```

Using a variable outside its scope is no better than using a variable that had never been declared in the first place. I cannot tell you how to fix this since I have no idea what this function is supposed to return. From its statement of purpose, I would have expected it to return `void`.

*Side note: If your compiler is not warning you that the statement `arr[i][j] / 2;` has no effect, you should enable more warnings; `-Wall -Wextra` is usually sufficient.*

Answer (score 2):

**First, the main issue:**

The variables in the `for` loop only last as long as those loops. The return statement is outside the loop, so neither `i` nor `j` actually exists at that point. That’s what them being “out of scope” means; you’re using variables which don’t actually exist there to use.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, the loop doesn’t actually *do* anything, but that isn’t what G++ is complaining about.

**Now, the question you asked:**

If you add `-fpermissive` to the G++ command line, it *will* accept that line, and use the last values of `i` and `j`. Unfortunately, those values are `r` and `c` respectively, which are past the end of the arrays; trying to access `a[i][j]` in this case is meaningless and will either return garbage data or crash the program.

**The solution:**

Think about what you actually want to return. What do you think `return a[i][j]` actually does here, and why do you want to return that value? It looks like you don’t actually use the return value, so why not just make the function `void`?

Comment: I attempted to write function as void, but now I only got one message back `ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @YokoKoko It [works on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/eEU1xT); do you have anything more complicated in the file than just what you’ve shown here?